# Retrieving User Input for Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio

Beginner programming including arrays and I'm having trouble just getting user input for the arrays. The printf functions I've included are just to check whether my arrays are working, the larger program I'm writing just needs to use these two arrays.

The input for the char array seems to work fine, I've tried a couple of different methods. However, the int array doesn't seem to work using the same diversity of methods I've used successfully with the char array. Not sure what I'm missing. Below is the code and the output when I run the program:

```
int main()
{

char grades[5]; // create array to store letter grades
int hours[5]; // array to store hours

puts("Please enter letter grades:"); // Input letter grades using fgets
fgets(grades, 5, stdin);

printf("Letter grade for course 3 is %c.\n", grades[2]);


int x = 0;

puts("Please enter course hours:\n");
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    scanf("%d", &hours[x]);
}

printf("Course hours for course 2 are: %d.\n", hours[1]);

return 0;
}
```

Output of this code:

```
Please enter letter grades:
ABCDF <- user input
Letter grade for course 3 is C.
Please enter course hours:

Course hours for course 2 are: -858993460.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: fgets() reads in at most *one less than size* characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.

Comment: `fgets` should be allowed to read the newline which will be stored in the array, so the array should be at least `char grades[7];`to allow for the newline and the string terminator. `fgets` should be passed `sizeof grades` as the length. As it is, data is left in the input buffer which upsets the following inputs.

Comment: @xing Your comment should really be the answer IMO.

Comment: 1.) Do not use ridiculously small buffers for `fgets()`, and if it is important for your program flow, check whether a complete line was read (seach for the newline character) - 2.) Almost always, do **not** use `scanf()`. You could use `sscanf()` on a line read by `fgets()` or some simpler methods, see also my [beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets(grades, 5, stdin);` captures `ABCD` of the input leaving `F` in the input stream. `scanf("%d", &hours[x]);` can't parse an int from `F` though it tries five times. Each failure leaves the `F` in the input stream.
Make buffers large enough for typical input.
Use `fgets` for all input. Parse with `sscanf` or others. Use the return of sscanf to make sure the parsing was successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void)
{

    char grades[50] = ""; // create array to store letter grades
    char line[50] = "";
    int hours[5] =  { 0}; // array to store hours
    int result = 0;

    puts("Please enter letter grades:"); // Input letter grades using fgets
    fgets(grades, sizeof grades, stdin);

    printf("Letter grade for course 3 is %c.\n", grades[2]);


    int x = 0;

    for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    {
        do {
            printf("Please enter course %d hours:\n", x + 1);
            fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin);
            result = sscanf( line, "%d", &hours[x]);
            if ( result == EOF) {
                printf ( "EOF\n");
                return 0;
            }
        } while ( result != 1);
    }

    printf("Course hours for course 2 are: %d.\n", hours[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just so I understand this, why do the char arrays have size 50?